# OAuth2.0 implementation in nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth, authorization, node-modules

I'm trying to develop a application using node.js, to support mobile app.  I've been able to find several resources on the web, however, most of the examples I come across fall into two camps:

1. Basic authentication // Im using my own authentication server to
   validate users.
2. OAuth

I don't want to use Google or some other third-party OAuth provider. I want to create own service provider same as features of google provider.
How can I fulfill my requirement with oauth2-provider node module?

Answer (score 0):

There are two nice projects that I'm aware of that can help you in that direction.

1. https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-oauth2-server
2. https://github.com/domenic/restify-oauth2

They're not perfect as they don't fully implement the OAuth 2.0 protocol, but it's a very good start.